# json filter nested array with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to pull with javascript: {"subNav0", "subNav1", "subNav2", "subNav3", "subNav4", "subNav5"}.

my json:

```
 var data = {
   "menus":{
      "GrandparentNav0":{
         "name":"TopNav",
         "items":[
            {
               "name":"ParentNav0",
               "iconClass":"",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "name":"ParentNav1",
                     "iconClass":"",
                     "items":[
                        {
                           "name":"subNav0",
                           "iconClass":""
                        },
                        {
                           "name":"subNav1",
                           "iconClass":""
                        },
                        {
                           "name":"subNav2",
                           "iconClass":""
                        },
                        {
                           "name":"subNav3",
                           "iconClass":""
                        },
                        {
                           "name":"subNav4",
                           "iconClass":""
                        },
                        {
                           "name":"subNav5",
                           "iconClass":""
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
  
   
};
```

i  know basic filter of an array:

```
data .forEach(function(o) {
 o.variable = o.variable.filter(s => s.value == value);
 });
```

I dont know how to get through menus, GrandparentNav0 to pull the subNav(s)

Comment: That's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). `data` is an object with some menus and submenus that have `items` which happen to be arrays of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "pull the subNav(s)" do you mean like accessing it through something like bracket notation?

```js
let subNavs = data['menus']['GrandparentNav0']['items'][0]['items']

console.log(subNavs)

/* would return
[
  {
    "name": "subNav0",
    "iconClass": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "subNav1",
    "iconClass": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "subNav2",
    "iconClass": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "subNav3",
    "iconClass": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "subNav4",
    "iconClass": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "subNav5",
    "iconClass": ""
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). This might be overkill for your requirements, however as you run into other use cases it's a Swiss army knife that makes these types of data interactions very clean

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { menus: { GrandparentNav0: { name: 'TopNav', items: [ { name: 'ParentNav0', iconClass: '', items: [ { name: 'ParentNav1', iconClass: '', items: [ { name: 'subNav0', iconClass: '' }, { name: 'subNav1', iconClass: '' }, { name: 'subNav2', iconClass: '' }, { name: 'subNav3', iconClass: '' }, { name: 'subNav4', iconClass: '' }, { name: 'subNav5', iconClass: '' } ] } ] } ] } } };

const result = objectScan(['menus.GrandparentNav0.items[0].items[0].items[*].name'], { reverse: false, rtn: 'value' })(data);

console.log(result);
// => [ 'subNav0', 'subNav1', 'subNav2', 'subNav3', 'subNav4', 'subNav5' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)